# CSS3 - How to display horizontally HTML5 elements at internet-explorer-8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I did a tutorial on how to set up a page displaying elements horizontally and it works fine at FF and Chrome, but not in IE8.

It's rendering the elements horizontally in FF and Chrome, and vertically at IE8. I suppose "box-orient: horizontal" would set the layout up for IE8.

I know IE8 does not support a lot of HTML5 and CSS3 features, but I have already used PIE to display boxes with round corners at this browser. I assume that IE8 would then support a basic feature such as displaying elements horizontally.

```
#box-wrap-inner {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;

    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;

    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    box-direction: normal;

    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;

}

#box1 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;

    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
}

#box2 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;

    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

#box3 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;

    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    box-ordinal-group: 3;
}
```

Comment: Just a note - Given the sketchy support across the board with this particular feature, you might be better off using the old techniques for this effect for a little while longer when doing anything other than sandbox/playground stuff. Not even IE10 and Safari get this right, and even Firefox has some pretty major bugs (doesn't support percentage widths).

Answer (score 3):

The [flexbox module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) is rather new and not supported in IE8 and IE9 (and in IE10 only an old version of this spec is supported with prefix `-ms`) <strike>and can't be simulated by PIE, you need some manual workaround like tables or need to live with the fact that it's broken in Internet Explorer (which normally is bad - their marketshare is still quite high).</strike>

[Support Chart](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

There is a **[shim available](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie)** to make it work in IE. Generally, if you run into trouble with some of newer HTML5/CSS-Stuff this site is very helpful: [Modernizr Polyfill List](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills).

EDIT:

It has the state of Candidate Recommendation now so you can expect it to become pretty stable and usable in the browsers soon. FF21 already dropped the prefix and IE10 is now available for win7 so one really can start to use this module.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility):

> > Internet Explorer 10 and Safari support an old incompatible draft version of the specification. They have not been updated to support the final version.

if IE10 hasn't gotten it right yet, you won't be able to do it in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

none of the new goodness works. use an ie specific stylesheet(s) and float your elements.

`<!--[if lt IE 9]><style> /** css to make ie8 play nicely **/ </style> <![endif]-->`

without seeing your styles, i cant tell you specifically what to to...but that's a tried and true way. just don't forget to clear your floats!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that IE9 doesn't support this particular feature, and IE10 supports an old version. Additionally, MS removed conditional comments with IE10, so you can't use that trick to make it behave like you can with the older ones.

Comment: which feature are you talking about? the question is regarding ie8, although floats will work in 9 and 10. pretty much all of them. i'm aware ie10 dropped support for conditionals, but again, this question is regarding ie8. you can target ie10 via media query's or using <code>@cc_on</code> which is (atm) very similar to conditionals. only bad thing about <code>@cc_on</code> is it's not supported in windows store.

Comment: It doesn't support the flexible box model stuff (nor does Safari, really, and Firefox has its own bugs). http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox  See also Christoph's answer and my comment to the question.